# iChat + facebook disconnection

Tags: facebook, ichat

Previously in SL I had chax to make sure iChat was always signed in.

Now on Lion I constantly find that iChat is disconnected from Facebook chat (jabber).

Does anyone have a clever idea to keep it connected?

Comment: Having the same exact problem. No ideas?

Comment: I've been experiencing the same thing, my hunch is that it's a server side problem on Facebook's end, as I've only noticed disconnects being a problem in the last few weeks. Before that I was running Facebook chat via iChat on Lion with no issues.

Answer (score 4):

Facebook will actively terminate your connection if you log-in from any other client like the Facebook web, or your mobile phone.

Even with just one client logged in, you should expect Facebook to close the connection anyway. This happens with everything I've tried, libpurple based clients (Admium, Pidgin on Linux...) gets disconnected now and then. Those clients do silently reconnect. For iChat, as you suggested, [chax](http://www.ksuther.com/chax/) can accept the dialog for you.

IMHO, It seems to me that Facebook is still struggling to make their chat service stable.

EDIT:
IF you want to reconnect without using chad, you can edit your crontab (using `crontab -e`) and add:

```
*/5 * * * * osascript -e ‘tell application “System Events” to if (processes whose name is “Messages”) exists then tell application “Messages” to log in’
```

This will make sure iChat stays connected, telling it to reconnect every five minutes.

Comment: thanks for the info. i am waiting for some solutions in iChat

Comment: @NikhilM, it seems there is no iChat-only solution for this problem as of the current version.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about keeping it alive, but I use this AppleScript to tell iChat to go online:

```
tell application "iChat" to set status to available
```

You could trigger that with Automator (or a dozen other ways) every hour or however often "constantly" is ...

Comment: How to do that, i am very new to mac