# Mountain Lion Messages Facebook Jabber connection problem

Tags: macos, messages, facebook, jabber, xmpp

This is a very weird problem I'm having with my Messages app on Mountain Lion. I have two accounts: a Google Talk and a Jabber account that is linked to my Facebook chat. Whenever I open my Messages app, my connection to Google Talk works just fine, but there is always a connection error with my Facebook account. But my Internet is working fine (like, I'm able to browse to www.facebook.com just fine). It's not an account authorization problem (incorrect username/password), trust me. To fix the problem, I need to go into Preferences -> delete my Facebook Jabber account -> recreate the account -> boom, connection is working fine again.

But, as soon as I log off from my Messages app (by closing it) and re-opening it, the problem re-emerges. Connection to Google Talk works fine, but a connection error with Facebook again. Perhaps this is an issue with Mountain Lion's implementation of Messages; because it is a newer app than the battle-tested iChat, there are still some rough edges needing to be sorted out.

Anyone having any tips regarding this problem?

PS: I did try to look at this question:  [iChat + facebook disconnection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22984/ichat-facebook-disconnection)

Comment: Are you able to solve the problem by just disabling and re-enabling the account?

Comment: I've had this issue since the beta app. disabling and re-enabling like @jtbandes says works for me though

Comment: What are the settings you are using in Messages for the facebook account - what server is it pointing at and which checkboxes are enabled?

Comment: I have the server connections correct: server chat.facebook.com, port 5222. All checkboxes are unchecked! The error messages I keep receiving (in a popup): *Messages lost the connection to the Jabber account “chat.facebook.com”.* _A network error occurred._

Also, I shouldn't have to keep deactivating and reactivating the account in order to make it work. Please tell me if you disagree that doing so would be quite user-unfriendly and annoying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These steps fixed the problem for me:

- Disable the account.
- Check 'Automatically find server and port'.
- Enable the account again.

Comment: Well...sometimes after doing this, the connection still sometimes barfs up. However, I realized that the quickest way to solve the problem at that point is to simply go to Messages->Accounts->uncheck and recheck chat.facebook.com. This will re-login and we are back!

Answer (score 2):

To provide the solution I found:
Sign in to Facebook on your browser, go to Account Settings > Security > Generate App Password

This will create a unique random password for you to use.  Use THAT password instead of your actual FB password.  Signed right in.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, then I do this:

- Disable account.
- Go to *Server Settings tab*.
- Uncheck: *Automatically find server and por*.
- Uncheck: *Use SSL*.
- Enable account again.

Now it works!, my settings:

- Server: chat.facebook.com
- Port: 522

Comment: That's bad joke dude, disable SSL for login. And port 522 !?

Comment: I know, but, doesn't work when I check the SSL options, :S.